# Exclude unused dependencies from package.json using ng-packagr

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I have a shared web/nativescript library. All nativescript files have a `**/*.tns.ts` filename format. Nativescript handles replacing any file with the same name but without the `tns` part with its `tns` counterpart. Thus if there is no `tns` counterpart it uses the same file as the web version. When I'm trying to build the library for the web the resulting code is free of nativescript code because the import chain is sure to not see any `*.tns.ts`. **However**, `ng-packagr` sees those files because it adds all imports in them as `peerDependencies` to the resulting `package.json` file even though there is no mention of those libraries in the resulting packaged code.

So my question is can I configure `ng-packagr` to also follow the chain of imports or skip some files for determining dependencies. I've tried setting adding `**/*.tns.ts` to my `exclude` list in my `tsconfig.json` with no luck.

Here is my `ng-package.json` file ...

```json
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/libs/core",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/index.ts",
    "styleIncludePaths": ["./node_modules"]
  }
}
```

I'm using `nx` to build and here is my relevant `project.json` ...

```json
{
  "name": "core",
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "projectType": "library",
  "sourceRoot": "libs/core/src",
  "prefix": "animalus",
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nx/angular:ng-packagr-lite",
      "outputs": ["{workspaceRoot}/dist/libs/core"],
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": "libs/core/tsconfig.lib.json",
        "project": "libs/core/ng-package.json"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "tsConfig": "libs/core/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
        },
        "development": {
          "tsConfig": "libs/core/tsconfig.lib.json"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },
    "test": {
      "executor": "@nx/jest:jest",
      "options": {
        "jestConfig": "libs/core/jest.config.ts",
        "passWithNoTests": true
      }
    }
  },
  "generators": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    }
  },
  "tags": []
}
```

Relevant versions:

```
   "@nx/angular": "16.3.2",
   "ng-packagr": "^15.2.2",
```

Comment: You may try to override tsconfig as described in https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/main/docs/override-tsconfig.md . As it seems ng-packgr using it's own tsconfig

Comment: Well too bad there isn't a cmd-line param for it. But I tried using the API as suggested and because this code is buried in a monorepo using nx I had other path problems. Not worth digging through. But oddly the end of the doc says "Overriding a tsconfig for Angular CLI users is straight forward as Angular CLI already uses the API. All you need to do is amend tsconfig.lib.json under the library folder." And that is exactly the set-up I have so it should work. But then again I really don't know what they mean by "amend tsconfig.lib.json under the library folder". Do they mean "have"? Check.